# Need to reload page after click on link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Please look at 1st image.
[image]

In this page i use LinkButton. ( Like... "sr001","sr003", and all )

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" onclick="lnkbtn_Click" 
ValidationGroup='<%# Eval("pid") %>'><%#Eval("productcode") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

**.cs page**

```
protected void lnkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id;
    id = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).ValidationGroup.ToString());
    string abc = "http://development.in/prod-more-info.aspx?pid=" + id;
    Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + abc.ToString() + "','_blank');</script>");
}
```

Now, When I clik on this link button process work successfully.

***BUT..............***

My design is disturb by this process, look at 2nd image..

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

**PLEASE HELP ME....**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a raw Response.Write is not advisable since you are literally just appending content to the response stream.

If you want to ensure your script shows up in the proper place and executes you should use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "MoreInfoPopup"))
{
    int id;
    id = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).ValidationGroup.ToString());
    string abc = "http://development.in/prod-more-info.aspx?pid=" + id;
    string script = String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>",abc);
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MoreInfoPopup", script);
}
```

Comment: Hi i have tried this on local and is working fine but when i made it online on server it is not working ..

Comment: @RajanVachhani There are so many factors at play that I don't have access to, that I probably won't be able to help you much. I would double check to make sure your code actually got deployed correctly, and that the Application Pool reset. Making a small change to the web.config is an easy way to force the site to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to reload the page once the button is clicked? If so, do a [response redirect](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903) to `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`.

The code:

`Response.Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);`

Comment: i had tried this but its not working as i m using code  Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + abc.ToString() + "','_blank');</script>");